# Scripts folder is not available in IIS Express when debugging Asp.Net Core application. Getting 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to run an Asp.Net Core application on a new development machine in Visual Studio 2022. The solution works on my old development machine and it works on other machines. But on my new development machine, when I run (debug) the Web application, the /scripts folder is not made available to the browser resulting in 404 errors. The application builds fine and my first page launches fine, but when I look at the console window in the browser I see 404 errors loading files from the /scripts folder. When I look at the "sources" in the browser I notice that no scripts folder appears at all. When I publish my solution and deploy it standalone on an IIS server it works. But for some reason, when I run my Web application from Visual Studio in IIS Express, the scripts folder isn't there. My old machine and my colleague's machine uses the exact same Web.config file and the applicationhost.config file also looks the same when I compare it. I really don't know what could be wrong? My guess is it could be a Visual Studio or IIS Express setting? Any ideas how I can solve this?

(Screenshots below to show what I'm seeing in the browser's developer tools)

Console:
[image]
Sources:

[image]

Comment: 404 error means that the url you are trying to access does not exist. According to your application, the url that should be localhost/security/login. But it is trying to access localhost/scripts/security/login. You could try to test if the url is the page you expected.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the problem, localhost:44318/scripts/security/login.js is indeed the correct script I am requesting. The problem is that the scripts folder doesn't appear at all when running the Web Application from Visual Studio. (But it IS there when my colleagues run the app on their machines and it is also there when I publish to a separate full-blown IIS server).

Comment: What version of IIS Express are you using? Maybe you can try switching the IIS Express version to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Our application uses TypeScript. (And it is a very old version of TypeScript too...)
I noticed that there were TypeScript build errors in the console even though the application could compile and run despite these build errors. I installed the applicable, old, version of TypeScript and when I rebuilt the project the project built without the TypeScript errors. However, this didn't resolve the issue since the /scripts folder was still not being made available by IIS Express to the browser. I then installed the NuGet package for Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild with the same corresponding old version of TypeScript that our application is using. When I built and ran the application then, the scripts folder appeared as expected and the application could run.

So to resolve this issue it was a combination of finding an old TypeScript installation file and installing it and also adding the NuGet Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package for that TypeScript version.

This resolved my issue. (It is still a mystery how it worked on other machines without the NuGet package, but I am leaving that be. I'm just glad this resolved my problem at last.)